# Esta regla hace que se tome archivo como directorio

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Cuando uso esta regla para evitar que a la página "proyecto" se le pueda pasar 2 parámetros, y reescribe la url, toma la página "proyecto" como directorio. Esto me crea un problema con la ruta del archivo .css

```
RewriteRule ^proyecto\/([a-z]+)\/(.+)$ /errores/err_404.php [L]
```

En lugar de llamar al archivo .css desde dominio/css/estilo.css, lo llama desde dominio/proyecto/css/estilo.css

Answer (score 0):

La solución es subir o bajar, en mi caso subir, tantos niveles como haga falta Hasta llegar al directorio raíz

```
 ../../css/ - 1 nivel 
 ../../../css/ - 2 niveles
```